# Accessing pointer with pointer to a literal

Tags: c, arrays, literals

I have to write some literals to an array, but I have just the address of the array, so I'm doing it by first creating a local array, filling it with the literals and second copy the content to the destination array. Here is an example:

```
void example(char *array) {
    char temp[] = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08 };    
    memcpy(array, temp, sizeof(temp));
}
```

This works pretty fine, but I'm searching for a way to do the same within one line instead of two. Has anyone an idea how to do this?

Comment: There is no advantage whatsoever to do this on one line instead of two... your code is already ideal when it comes to readability and performance.

Comment: One line:`char temp[] = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08 };memcpy(array,temp, sizeof(temp));` Just remove the line break ;)

Comment: Hmm,.. well I'll have to access many pointers, but if there is no other solution, I'm gonna do it in this way everytime.

Comment: Wouldn't it look a bit better with `static char temp[]` ?

Comment: @alk Well, AFAIK, `char temp[] = { ...} ` means really two things: declaring global unnamed array, and declaring local stack pointer variable. While `static char[]` is really one global array with reduced visibility. Though it's quite probable that the compiler will optimize out that stack variable `temp` anyway.

Comment: @user4419802 The most correct form is `const char temp[]`. There is no reason to allocate a table on constants in the .data section of the memory.

Comment: @Lui There is no difference between explicitly allocating a pointer, or implicitly doing so by using a string literal or compound literal. The data you copy must be stored in memory. No data can be stored in thin air. All data which resides in memory has an address. Address == pointer. So leave your code as it is, do not attempt any pre-mature optimization.

Comment: @user4419802: As per the OP's code `temp` isn't a pointer, but an array.

Comment: @Lundin Agree. Actually, I use `static const char[]` on such occasions.

Comment: @alk An array which decays into a pointer to the first element when passed to memcpy...

Comment: @alk Well, what if to do: `printf("%p %p", &array, &temp);` I wonder, if they  will be "near" each other.

Comment: I've put my various comments into an answer of my own, as I believe that all the current answers are inferior to the original code. Although they do answer the question - a request which doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @user4419802: Putting an `int i` just above `char temp[] = ...` I get `...db0` for `temp`'s address and `... dbc` for `i`'s address. So what? That is 8bytes + 4 padding bytes.

Comment: @alk That means they are both on the stack, and `i` is after `temp` (lower address). Make `static char temp` and they will be _totally_ different.

Comment: With or without `static` `temp()` won't be compiled into a pointer, won't it? @user4419802

Comment: @alk That depends upon compiler. If `/*auto*/ char temp[]` would not really produce a (stack variable) pointer, it is only due to optimization.

Comment: If not used in a function declaration `T D1[] = <initialiser>;` defines an array `D1` of elements typed `T` with a size defined by its initialiser. (See C11 draft 6.7.6.2/4) @user4419802 And I see no evidence the `static` key word should have an influence on this.

Comment: @alk The difference will be clear when using this array, because C arrays are cast'ed to pointers in nearly all possible C-expressions. While `static char[]` already has such pointer implicitly defined (it's just a constant), `auto char[]` has to create it on the stack.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm writing this answer down because you commented that you want to do it in one line in order to avoid having "*to access many pointers*". But you won't. Any decent compiler will optimize this. GCC with `-O1` produces this code on `x86_64` for your example, unchanged. It doesn't even call `memcpy`:

```
example:
.LFB12:
    .cfi_startproc
    movb    $1, (%rdi)
    movb    $2, 1(%rdi)
    movb    $3, 2(%rdi)
    movb    $4, 3(%rdi)
    movb    $5, 4(%rdi)
    movb    $6, 5(%rdi)
    movb    $7, 6(%rdi)
    movb    $8, 7(%rdi)
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
```

To explain: `$1`, `$2` etc are elements of your literal, and `%rdi` is the register that contains the first argument to `example` i.e. the pointer you named `array`.

Just use the two readable lines.

Answer (score 3):

This is less readable than your code, I'd say, but if you simply must do it in one line...

```
memcpy(array, "\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08", sizeof("\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08") - 1);
```

Comment: Why `-1` in `sizeof(...)-1`?

Comment: @CoolGuy, to remove the '\0'

Comment: Because strings are 0-termianted and we don't want to copy the zero at the end. ;-)

Comment: @ForceBru , Oh yeah . I forgot that `"..."` are already NUL-terminated.

Comment: This is really just obfuscation of the original code.

Comment: @Lundin No disagreement here.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a compound literal:

```
memcpy(array, (char []) {0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08},
       sizeof ((char []) {0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08}));
```

You can use a define to not have to repeat the array (this is more error-prone if you have to modify the array elements):

```
#define ARRAY  ((char []) {0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08})

memcpy(array, ARRAY, sizeof ARRAY);
```

Comment: I think you missed a "{", but I can't edit you post. :-(

Comment: Well this looks beatiful for me, but I'm getting a "taking address of temporary array"-Error.

Comment: As a note, this won't compile in all environments. GCC seems fine, though, which probably covers most people's cases.

Comment: To clarify my last comment, it looks like this is valid C99, which I thought was what we were compiling here at work, but it wouldn't compile for me. So long as you have a reasonably standards-compliant compiler, you're probably fine :)

Comment: It is not "looking beautiful". It exposes a previously local variable to the global namespace. That's ugly. At the very least use a file scope `static const` rather than a macro. Or better yet, leave the code as it was but make the local variable `static const` (unless of course thread-safety is an issue).

Comment: @Lundin this compound literal has automatic storage duration, no object with static storage duration is used, contrary to any solution involving a static object.

Comment: @ColeCameron compound literals are constructs valid since c99, any decent (which means unfortunately not all) should support them.

Comment: @ouah I was referring to the macro. The compound literal indeed has automatic storage duration, but will in practice get optimized into a static constant with all optimizations enabled.

Answer (score 2):

The canonical way to write the code would be this:

```
void example(char *array) {
    static const char temp[] = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08 };    
    memcpy(array, temp, sizeof(temp));
}
```

This is very readable and also the fastest possible, since the local constant will not be allocated on the stack per function call. But of course, that's something that the compiler will likely optimize anyhow.

There is no reason what-so-ever to attempt to manually optimize this code further. String literals will make the code harder to read. Compound literals will have local scope and are in theory allocated on the stack for each function call, which would make the code slower in theory - in practice the compiler will likely optimize the compound literal so that it isn't pushed on the stack for each function call.

If several functions need to use the same constant, then declare it at file scope, but keep it `static const` so that you don't clutter down the global namespace more than necessary.

Comment: As a side note, there _is_ the difference between `char`, `static char` and `static const char`. Here is the code to play with - http://ideone.com/8KsALZ  See, how `temp` is changing.

Comment: @user4419802 That's expected with no optimizations. `char` = stack, `static char` = .data, `static const char` = .rodata. If you however compile with all optimizations on (gcc -o3 for example), you'll notice that you get the very same address no matter which form you use. That's why for example the original code or compound literals don't add any overhead, as mentioned in my answer.

Comment: When optimizations are on, no one, except the compiler itself, can predict the output code. Yet giving some hint to the compiler, is still a good idea.

Comment: Which is why I believe that the above code is canonical, it should give the same machine code as the code with full optimization enabled. (Although the compiler might think it is smarter yet to allocate "array" and "temp" in adjacent memory and make its optimization decision based on that.)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming machine is LSB

`*(unsigned long long *)array = 0x0807060504030201;`

P.S. Well, don't take it too serious ;-)

P.P.S. Let me throw in another argument against using `char[]` (instead of `static char[]`) inside function.

Although the optimizing compiler can *sometimes* rule out the annoying stack variable, but it's not always possible. Consider, for example, invoking some other function, say, `printf("%s", temp)`. It looks quite innocent, yet, as the second argument to `printf` is not known as `const`, the compiler *must* create *the copy of the whole array* `temp` on the stack, before passing it to `printf`.

For some large array, this could be really painful!